# Why do I get the "insufficient allowance" error when I call this function with another address?

Tags: solidity, remix, hardhat

```
function redeemCollateralForStreal(
    address tokenCollateralAddress,
    uint256 amountCollateral
) public {

    uint8 tokenDecimals = getDecimals(tokenCollateralAddress);
    uint256 amount = amountCollateral * (10**tokenDecimals);
    uint256 strealToBurn = calculateEquivalentAmountToMint(tokenCollateralAddress, amountCollateral);
    uint256 _amount = strealToBurn * 1e18; 
    // Calculate the fee
    uint256 fee = amount * 5 / 100;
    // Ensure that the user has enough collateral deposited
    require(_collateralDeposited[msg.sender][tokenCollateralAddress] >= amountCollateral, "Not enough collateral deposited");
    // Deduct the collateral from the user's deposited collateral
    _collateralDeposited[msg.sender][tokenCollateralAddress] -= amountCollateral;
    // Deduct the fee from the collateral
    uint256 balances =  amount -= fee;
   
    // Transfer the collateral to the user
    bool success = IERC20(tokenCollateralAddress).transfer(msg.sender, balances);
    require(success, "Transfer of collateral failed");
   
    // Burn the Streal tokens
    burnStreal(_amount);
    
}
```

this function allows when called by the user basically allows the smart contract to refund the collateral deposited by the user, but when I call the function, it gives out the insufficient allowance error...

if you have an idea why this is happening please share your experience.

Comment: Can you share your `burnStreal()` method too?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma 
` function burnStreal(uint256 amountToBurn) private moreThanZero(amountToBurn) nonReentrant {
        _burnStreal(amountToBurn, msg.sender, msg.sender);

    }

    function _burnStreal(
        uint256 amountToBurn,
        address onBehalfOf,
        address strealFrom
    ) private {
        strealFrom = msg.sender;
        mintedStreal[onBehalfOf] -= amountToBurn;
        bool success = transferFrom(strealFrom, address(this), amountToBurn);
        require(success, "failed to burn");
        burn(amountToBurn); 
    }`

Comment: Did you give `allowance` to the contract from your wallet before hitting `redeemCollateralForStreal()` function?

Comment: Yes I did, and I got the error still...